# Merging 2 video input source into 1 output

Tags: live, output

Is there a way to do this? For example i want to have a single projector displaying a live feed from a camera and a video playing from a laptop.

Its sort of like any overlay of 2 videos playing at the same time.

So far all searches have either return a splitter or a switch. Neither which is what i want

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit it using an editing software like Premimere, Sony Vegas or any other.
I don't know how you do it in Sony Vegas but in Premiere you just place both videos in the sequence and resize them.

That's pretty basic editing, try to search for the best editing software that works best for you and search for tutorial about that software.

If you need it for live broadcasting then you need a professional live video broadcasting software or use what you got in the platform you're broadcasting in.